# Logic of splitting planes in Altium of different "voltage areas"

Tags: voltage, pcb-layers

If I understand correctly there is a concept of whole areas on a single plane for different voltages (as shown below).

They made an area on another layer an area  for 12 V nets and on the same layer.

As I see it we have a connector and ground plane and we have traces from the connector. I don't understand how these different voltage "areas" on the same plane function.

Do we have a ground plane in such a situation? Why do we use voltage planes and not traces? We have  components that need traces to power them. How do voltage planes transform into traces going to components?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Altium allows you to define any layer in the stack up as either a signal layer or a power plane layer. In a signal layer you specify where copper goes; this could be traces or planes (by using something like a polygon pour). With power planes you specify the inverse/negative - lines on a power plane create different sections on that layer. Clicking on a defined section allows you to assign a net to that section, and once this is done vias with the same net name will connect to this plane section.

Based on the images, your PCB is probably a four layer board (although you can confirm this or let us know if it is different). The outer two layers are used for signals and some power. It then probably has two inners layers, one of which will be a continuous ground across the board, and the remaining layer is used for power, in this case to distribute 12V. As the 12V is not required everywhere, I also suspect that only a section has been set to 12V and the rest as GND, to further reduce the impedance of the ground connection across the PCB.

Planes are generally used for power and ground because they provide a low impedance path (compared with traces).

Comment: Hm, can outer layers be set as plane? I don't think so in older versions at least, not sure about newer...

Comment: Just checked and @TimWilliams is entirely correct. Altium does not let you define outer layers as power planes

Comment: Hello Graham,Impedance is calculated by the trace width.
So plane is just a very thick trace?
Power plane and signal trace have the ground plane as reference?
Thanks.